# PWM controll on digital pin 3 Arduino Due (C)

Tags: c, arduino, controls, pwm, arduino-due

I'm trying to control a fan on my Arduino Due board with Arduinos own [motor shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoMotorShieldR3) and I have encountered a problem. I want to send a PWM signal to my fan, and here comes the problem, pin 3 is channel less..

What I can find there is no channel for digital pin 3?

The code works, I have tested it with other pins and I get the requested value when I measure it on a multimeter.

In Due's [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc11057.pdf) there is not a single thing about it. On the motor shields webpage did I find that pin 3 is the one to use and on Arduino Uno it works great.

There is also a way to use digital pin 11, but it's the same here, no channel.

Does any one have a solution or answer way it's this way?

Comment: Well, it should work. Have you set the output to analog out? Maybe you can post relevant parts of your code?

Comment: @ThomasKilian I solved  it by cutting digital pin 3 of the motor shield and drag a wire from another digital port on the arduino to pin 3. It works but is a cheap solution.

I did find out that you can emulate a sinus wave with a timer that is connected to digital pin 3 on the arduino, but this is a little more complex. 

In the datasheet it says that PC28 control PWM, table 39.2! 

I will put out exactly how I did it in a couple of days when I have time for it.